# Check if the end user is admin

Tags: php, mybb

I've to check whether the end user is admin or not, I've done right (I hope) but it fails to check. Here is what I'm using;

```
function checked_already($pid,$input)
{
    global $db;
    if ($mybb->user['usergroup'] != "4")
    {
        error_no_permission();
    }
    $query = $db->simple_select("users", "username", "uid='{$input}' OR username='{$input}'");
    $user = $db->fetch_array($query);

    if (!$user['username'])
    {
        echo "Nothing found!!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

But it fails to check if the end user is admin. :/ No error at all. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not used $mybb in global. Try this;

```
function checked_already($pid,$input)
{
    global $db, $mybb;
    if ($mybb->user['usergroup'] != "4")
    {
        error_no_permission();
    }
    $query = $db->simple_select("users", "username", "uid='{$input}' OR username='{$input}'");
    $user = $db->fetch_array($query);

    if (!$user['username'])
    {
        echo "Nothing found!!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never, never use `global` variables. It's architecture smell. Pass your context as parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed a bad way to work on but MyBB works that way as far as I checked.

Comment: Just a note: the proper way in MyBB to check whether the user is admin or not  is not checking the usergroup 4, there might be custom admin groups. This is the way: if ($mybb->user['cancp']){...} If the user is admin the value is 1, else 0.